# error in starting the program and adding component

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-7

I am new to delphi,

when opening one unit I get this error message,

> Error reading cp_port.BaudRate: Property BaudRate does not exist. Ignore the error and continue?

and when I try to run the program, some components that added is gone, I mean, I need to install it again, but no luck, still my program can't start?

how can i solve this?

I tried to Google it but I can't find the answer. help me. thanks

Comment: You need to identify the component and make sure that you have the version of the component that matches your source code. Thinking more broadly you need to learn to use revision control and document third party dependencies.

Comment: i am using Delphi 7 on Windows 8, is it because of compatibility issue? or not? help me pls.

Comment: The problem is that you don’t have exact component installed in your environment.
Tell us what type cp_port of, maybe somebody will help you to find the component.

Comment: @Arkady i already installed CPort, and i am missing BaudRate property.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan they tried it on windows 7 and works fine, but when i try to use windows 8, there are many error.

Comment: Windows 7 does not ship with Delphi design time packages! Your Windows 7 machine and your Windows 8 machine have different design time packages. Again, this is purely down to your code, and your Delphi installations.

Comment: ok, thanks, i'll try to ask help from the one who wrote the code, thanks @DavidHeffernan

Answer (score 4):

There is a mismatch between the .dfm file and the component code for the object named `cp_port`. The version of the component used to create the .dfm file includes a property named `BaudRate`. That property does not exist in the version of the component that is trying to read the .dfm file when you encounter the error.

The solution to such an error is to make sure that you use the same version of the component as was used to make the .dfm file.